# Does Android OS Updates Interfere With Flutter Apps

Tags: android, flutter, dart

My flutter application isn't working as expected as to some features of the application. I noticed this started after a recent Android OS update was performed on the device on which I'm running my app. The app fully functions well on another device of mine that haven't been updated yet.

I'm just wondering if an OS update could cause an app to misbehave. The problem itself is with the local storage used to store application settings.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "isn't working as expected"?

Comment: It depends what your app is doing.
e.g. I have developed an app which was searching and delete identical files. It was OK until Android 4.4 because of this changes: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4  , see "mportant Behavior Changes"

So, you have to identify what are the changes in the new Android version and see if they should affect your app.

Comment: Thank you @MarcelPreda will look into it